What is Resonance localized at a bound neutron energy level?
Please see the article [1]. In Table 4, the first 2 energies are negative, meaning resonance from a bound state. what does resonance from a bound state mean physically? How to visualize it.
[1]: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306454914000590?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=8e57d9151cb03ada

Consider what optical absorption looks like in a Lorentz oscillator model near a transition between bound states. Same thing here - there is the ground state and another state that together provides a larger overlap integral for the scattering process. Seen over and over and over again in neutron scattering data, and is used to map out nuclear energy levels.
